# Construction of a complete countable set from a complete uncountable set?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $A$ is an uncountable complete set in a separable Hilbert space. Is it possible to find a complete countable subset $B$ of $A$?

As an example, take the uncountable set $A = \{ | \alpha \rangle \}$
$$
| \alpha \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{n!} |n\rangle
$$
where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary complex number. Every converging series $\{ \alpha_j\}$ of in the complex plane induces a complete countable set $\{| \alpha_j \rangle\}$. Is it always possible to reduce an uncountable complete set to a countable set that is complete?

My idea to show that a complete countable subset $B$ always exists looks like this (forgive me my physics notation):

Since the Hilbert space is separable, there exists an ONB denoted by $\{|n \rangle \}$. We denote the elements of $A$ by $| \alpha \rangle$. Since $A$ is complete, each basis element can be written like
$$
| n \rangle = \sum_{i} a_{n,i} |\alpha_{n,i} \rangle
$$
An element of the Hilbert space can be written as
$$
| \psi \rangle = \sum_{n} c_n | n \rangle = \sum_n \sum_i c_n a_{n,i} | \alpha_{n,i} \rangle 
$$
The set $B = \{ |\alpha_{n,i} \rangle \}$ is complete and countable. Is there anything wrong with this line of thought?

Comment: If a question gets closed do not simply repost it. This is a good way to lose your posting privileges.

Comment: I edited the question and only then reposted. The original question was only the first two lines